# Is 'Lock' taking CPU time?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I have 6 threads.
One of the thread get in some scope and turn on the 'lock' and all the other 
threads are waiting and want to enter to the same scope.

Now, Is the other threads will get CPU Time? Does the other thread are in the thread schedule ? 
I understand that all the other thread are in waiting state - but the CPU will try to make the thread continue and try to get in the scope ( even if the scope is not accessible )

Comment: My understanding is that the other threads will still receive timeslices, which they will use to check the status of the lock. If the lock is still in place, they will go back to sleep, otherwise they will proceed.

Comment: this is what i understood also - but this takes CPU time ... so this is kind of busy waiting - and this is very bad.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When trying to enter a lock that's already taken, threads first spinlock for a while, and finally suspend and enter a wait state.

They still burn CPU time while they spin, but no longer once they wait.

Comment: To expand a little: the spinwait is done because it is cheaper than a kernel transition and thus optimises for the case where the lock is only lightly contended.

Comment: what is spinlock  ? can you answer in 1 sentence ?

Comment: @Royi The thread keeps checking if the look is free in a loop. Something like `while(!lock.TryEnter()){}` Burns CPU, but avoids the overhead of a kernel transition and thread scheduling. It's good if the lock becomes free soon, but bad if it takes longer. That's why `lock` spinlocks for a short while, and then waits.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how lock works. You won't give anyone more "cpu time". If you're locking you might introduce wait periods and potentially deadlocks where the threads are waiting for each other.