# What's the correct way to implement SemaphoreSlim in this context

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I heard about `SemaphoreSlim` to limit thread access to something, but I don't know its exact usage in `async` context?

```
if (!LOGS_FILE.Equals(string.Empty) && File.Exists(LOGS_FILE))
{
    using (StreamWriter STREAM_WRITER = new StreamWriter(LOGS_FILE, true))
    {
        STREAM_WRITER.WriteLine(LOG);
    }
}

if (IsDebuggerAttached())
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(LOG);
}

ALL_LOGS += LOG + "\n";
```

Comment: What do you mean by `async`? Which method is calling this code? If you call this in a desktop application's UI thread after `await` you don't need locking.

Comment: Please follow .NET naming conventions in code that you post here. Even if you don't follow the regular conventions within your company or whatever, it's *really* helpful to follow them in public sample code.

Comment: Right, but I just took this sample from my personal app, without modifying it

Comment: @ShaderCraft while you're using this as a learning exercise, custom naming makes it *hard* for others to read your code. As for the *actual* problem, `SemaphoreSlim` is a specialized class and most of the time you don't need it - unless you're building a synchronization library. There are better high level types to perform asynchronous operations with limited concurrency. For example, a `var block=ActionBlock<string>(line=>File.AppendAllTextAsync(file,line))` will append lines to a file asynchronously *and* buffer the input, so callers won't have to wait at all.

Comment: @ShaderCraft - I think it's understood that you've taken a sample of your code without modifying it. The alternative is that created code that violated the standard naming conventions. We assume you didn't. What Jon asked was for you to modify your code before posting. Please do so.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @Panagiotis Kanavos pointed out, using `lock() {  }` block is better, this how you could implement it instead of SemaphoreSlim:

```
    object lockObject = new object(); //Global field

    ...

    if (!LOGS_FILE.Equals(string.Empty) && File.Exists(LOGS_FILE))
    {
        lock(lockObject)
        {
            using (StreamWriter STREAM_WRITER = new StreamWriter(LOGS_FILE, true))
            {
                STREAM_WRITER.WriteLine(LOG);
            }
        }
    }

    if (IsDebuggerAttached())
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(LOG);
    }

    ALL_LOGS += LOG + "\n";
```

Consider using a logging library, so you won't confuse yourself dealing with concurrent calls and other things.

Comment: The question asked how to perform the synchronization "in async context".

Comment: Some people were complaining about using SemaphoreSlim

Comment: People were complaining about `SemaphoreSlim.Wait` which is completely inappropriate for an async architecture.

Comment: I forgot about it, its correct now

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
try
{
    await SEMAPHORE_SLIM.WaitAsync();

    if (!LOGS_FILE.Equals(string.Empty) && File.Exists(LOGS_FILE))
    {
        using (StreamWriter STREAM_WRITER = new StreamWriter(LOGS_FILE, true))
        {
            STREAM_WRITER.WriteLine(LOG);
        }
    }

    if (IsDebuggerAttached())
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(LOG);
    }

    ALL_LOGS += LOG + "\n";
}
finally
{
    SEMAPHORE_SLIM.Release();
}
```

EDIT: Added try finally block

Comment: `.Wait()` is the opposite of async. It's unsafe too - the semaphore will never be released if an error occurs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What about `.WaitAsync()` ?

Comment: Why lock at all? Besides SemaphoreSlim isn't as lightweight as you think it is. It doesn't put the thread to sleep like `lock()` does only because it uses spinwaiting - it runs an infinite loop that keeps a core occupied at 100%, thus preventing other threads from accessing the code. This is *very* expensive in terms of both power and throughput. In a web application running on a 4-core machine, 4 concurrent requests can freeze the app just to log

Comment: @ShaderCraft a better option would be to use a dedicated thread (or rather task) to write to a log file and use queue to send lines to it. Logging libraries like Serilog already take care of such things

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I had a bug concerning concurrent write to the file because this was called from different threads, I searched on the net about things like this, so SemaphoreSlim was useful in my case, I don't want to use any 3rd party libs because I need full control of logging, so I made my own _private_ logging library that fits my case

Comment: @ShaderCraft That has a name: reinventing the wheel.

Comment: What does "I need full control of logging" mean?

Comment: Right, I'll use a logging library. This is just a test app because I'm still learning c#, so I'm experimenting stuff. @PanagiotisKanavos this code won't ever run in other machine nor a web server. anyway thanks, I'll use `lock()`.

Comment: Lots of misinformation here in the comments about how the `SemaphoreSlim` is working, about occupying CPU cores 100% etc.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: It does busy-wait *the way it is used here, with `.Wait()`*.  If used properly with `await`, then there is no busy-wait.

Comment: @BenVoigt please try running [this program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pR56sW) in your PC. The `PerformanceCounter` is not supported on the .NET platform used by the dotnetfiddle.net site, but in my PC I get CPU utilization measurements below 10%. This proves that the `semaphore.Wait()` isn't busy-looping for one second per thread. Then if I comment the `semaphore.Wait();` line and uncomment the `Thread.SpinWait` line, the CPU jumps to 100%.

Comment: @BenVoigt honestly I am shocked that at least 2 experienced .NET developers believed that Microsoft would have released a so poor implementation of a basic synchronization primitive.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: Ok, it does have a kernel wait handle `SemaphoreSlim.AvailableWaitHandle` that lets it enter an efficient wait.  But then it is no longer "slim"

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: Also, my earlier comment was correct.  It [does use a busy-wait](https://download.microsoft.com/download/B/C/F/BCFD4868-1354-45E3-B71B-B851CD78733D/PerformanceCharacteristicsOfSyncPrimitives.pdf).  After some time it gives up on busy-waiting and waits on a kernel handle.  If you use `WaitAsync` as intended, then there isn't a busy-wait.

Comment: @BenVoigt AFAIK the `SemaphoreSlim` is not the only primitive that spin-waits for a few nanoseconds before putting the thread to sleep. The `lock` [does it too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376480/is-lock-taking-cpu-time/9376526#9376526). They do it because it is beneficial for performance. The `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` not doing it means that on average it performs worse. It is significantly allocatey too, because it doesn't take advantage of `ValueTask`s.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: No, because `WaitAsync` doesn't wait.  It queues a completion callback.

Comment: @BenVoigt it does, and later when another execution flow calls `Release`, the completion callback is scheduled on the `ThreadPool`. That's not cheap. Have you done any benchmarks? I would be surprised if the `WaitAsync` outperforms the `Wait`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: You said "The callback is scheduled on the threadpool" but that depends on your synchronization context.  It might simply be called from inside `Release` if the awaiter isn't configured to disable synchronous continuation.  In any case, it's the same cost as every other async/await and much cheaper than doing multiple kernel calls.

Comment: @BenVoigt the last time I checked the `SemaphoreSlim` schedules the completion of the queued `TaskCompletionSource` on the `ThreadPool`, because it is configured with `TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously`. Depending on the synchronization context, you might suffer a second redirection on top of that. If you are for a betting, I am willing to bet 500 rep points that the `Wait` has larger throughput than the `WaitAsync`. I bet that multiple concurrent flows can do a larger total number of acquire-release operations per second. Are you in?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: Counting acquire-release operations per second is not very interesting because the time wasted will actually change based on the operation being protected by the semaphore.  But if you ask a well-written question about "cost of SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync(), where do the CPU cycles go?", drop me a link, and I'll bounty it, awarding it to you if your answer has a good explanation with research references / evidence.

Comment: @BenVoigt the operation being protected by the semaphore will be in both cases `count++`. If we want to measure the synchronization overhead, the workload must be absolutely minuscule. Honestly I am not in the mood for asking questions. I prefer an experimental demonstration of the truth.

Comment: Your "the workload must be absolutely minuscule" quite obviously stacks the deck in favor of spinning, and gives results that aren't representative of real scenarios.  (After all, if I need mutual exclusion on an increment, I have `InterlockedIncrement` and/or partial sums that get reduced in the end)

Comment: @BenVoigt what kind of workload do you think that it would be representative of real scenarios, and would also be suitable for comparing these two methods for performance? If we do something heavy, like fetching something from the internet with the `HttpClient`, the synchronization overhead will be dwarfed, the performance will be similar, and we will not learn anything.